# Python Xpath conundrum. I can select the link, try to click, no go

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath

My xpath identifies the link I want to click, in code, the clicking does nothing.

Tried various ways of landing on the link, they all work, still, the click does not.

Here is the xpath that gets me to the link in the html below:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[text()='2009 CR 00203']/ancestor::a").click()
```

I am expecting the click to work and travel to a new page which is what happens when manually accessing the website like a typical visitor.

Here is the relevant HTML:

```
<td id="grid$row:47$cell:3" class="bookmarkablePageLinkPropertyColumnLink">
    <span>
    <!-- $Id: BookmarkablePageLinkPanel.html,v 1.2 2015/07/17 21:22:42 zcarter Exp $ -->
        <a href="?x=oETOKPmVudMuqONlkX1Tiv3Gtb5F5sedgQTMNLZ3tcAonXM5HcVTKxw7e-*sHrZvlNHuylIDXkrxaTtpmME4HA" id="grid$row:47$cell:3$link" onclick="$('#processingDialog').dialog('open');">
            <i id="id1d6"></i>
            <span>2009 CR 00203</span>
        </a>
    </span>
</td>
```

Just to clarify, the actual code is intended to iterate through a list of case numbers.  So it is actually this code:  (Ignore formatting, couldn't get it to look as it does in my code, formatting wise).

```
for case in case_lst:
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[text()=case]/ancestor::a").click()
    # grab data from resulting page after click
    driver.back() # returning to previous page with more case links....
```

Answer (score 1):

Try javascript click.

```
ele = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[text()='2009 CR 00203']/ancestor::a")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",ele)
```

Comment: I like the out of the box thinking, but still, error message, 'NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element'

Comment: But, I am actually using a variable for the case number above in the actual code.  I have list of case numbers and I am iterating through that list.  So, is it possible, since this is the EXACT code, that the xpath does not like the variable usage, it has spaces and all.    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[text()=case]/ancestor::a") ?

Comment: Try this `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[text()='" + str(case) + "']/ancestor::a") `

Comment: And.....@supputuri, that is a BINGO!  Wow, how did I miss that.  I have tons of code where I have to flip flop int and str, and just overlooked it.  Worked great!  Thanks.  Now, how to I approve this answer?

Comment: You can accept the answer by clicking on the hallow check mark below the down vote button on the left hand side in my answer. Also feel free to upvote.

Comment: Clicked on the upvote.  That answer saved me significant hours.  Sometimes it is the simple things.  There is no visible check mark, just a flag there.  So upvote it is!  Thanks again.

Comment: Check [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) to know how to accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

One issue with your code is that you are using the `case` variable inside your locator but it's being interpreted as a string "case".

```
"//span[text()=case]/ancestor::a"
```

should be

```
"//span[text()=" + case + "]/ancestor::a"
```

The updated code should look like

```
for case in case_lst:
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[text()=" + case + "]/ancestor::a").click()
    # grab data from resulting page after click
    driver.back() # returning to previous page with more case links....
```

If that gives you an error that the element can't be found, it's likely that the element is inside of an `IFRAME` or that you need to add a wait for clickable to make sure that part of the page is loaded. Links to the docs for those two cases are below.

[docs for switching to an IFRAME](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it)

[docs for waiting for clickable](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable)